# Is there a word that describes the swift and skillful covering of the natural emotions?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Some people become adept at completely hiding their natural reaction to a situation. Some may call this *lying*, or just control.

Neither of these describes when it is done swiftly in the moment, and done with such skill that most observers will not see the *'glimmer'* of the natural reaction.

I think this is a form of lying, psychoanalytically-speaking, but I do not think malice is an inherent condition here - sometimes a leader or a parent will swiftly hide concern from their children or those who look to them for guidance. This latter case is not evil.

---

I would think that *'deft'* is related, but am unsure if **the element of concealment** is an inherent quality of *deftness*.  I am speaking to *the swift-covering of the natural response*, and want a word identifying that a natural reaction began, ***evanescently***, and was deftly replaced by another visage.

Comment: Poker face, poker-faced.

Comment: I like *poker-faced* as well, but *stoic* or *impassive* may also apply.

Comment: S: (adj) deadpan, expressionless, impassive, poker-faced, unexpressive (deliberately impassive in manner) "deadpan humor"; "his face remained expressionless as the verdict was read" (*WordNet Search 3.1*)

Comment: Stolid might work.

Answer (score 5):

Usually I'd say, "they had a good poker face."

> poker face (plural poker faces) (poker)
>
> 1. An impassive facial expression cultivated to prevent other players from determining whether one's
>      actions in the game are the result of a quality hand, or of bluffing.
> 2. Any similar expression used to
>      prevent giving away one's motives, feelings, or situation.

**Edit:** It has been brought to my attention that I failed to cite the above c&p.  The definition is from [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poker_face)

Comment: Poker face implies a mask-like facies - meaning showing no emotion at all - that is not skillful concealment

Comment: Not necessarily, I've often heard it used in the context of having a person's expression not change from whatever it was before.

It doesn't necessarily need to be a stonewall.

Comment: That might be the case - the point I was making is that it does not have the connotation of skill and deftness indicated by OP

Comment: Again, I'd disagree.  It takes a lot of skill to maintain a good poker face.

Comment: It's not really a matter of opinion - Show me which description of this term implies adroit concealment

Comment: @user49727 It's within the actual definition: "used **to prevent giving away** one's motives, feelings..." Having a poker face means you are deliberately emotionless, straight-faced, impassible etc. It's a valid answer but one which was first provided by Blessed Geek.

Comment: But having a mask-like face is not 'skilful' hiding - it's simply unrevealing of 'any' emotion - that's just maintaining an unrevealing straight face (as in a poker game) no matter what.

Comment: @user49727: I could also imply a maintained face.  If I looked happy and someone pissed me off.  A good poker face would express no change. Therefore a skillful hiding of what I'm actually feeling (anger) while I appear happy.

Comment: If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Comment: @tchrist: I have provided a link as requested.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider *[composed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/composed)*

> free from agitation : calm; especially : self-possessed
>
> *He had told us he felt nervous about the performance, but he seemed perfectly composed when he walked onto the stage.*

Note that *composed* does not necessarily mean an appearance that is at odds with the person's true emotional state.

Similarly you might consider *[self-possessed](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/self-possessed)*

> having control of one's emotions, etc

SUPPLEMENT

On second thought, perhaps the verb *[mask](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/mask)* applies

> To conceal one's real personality, character, or intentions.

You could say, *To calm their children, the parents masked their fear of the marauding bear.*

Comment: nor does composed describe the *adroit concealment in the moment* - to me 'composed' more describes a state of preparation

Comment: In the movie *All That Jazz*, Roy Scheider wakes up, looks in the mirror and is obviously feeling tired, ill, hung over and miserable. He waves his hand in front of his face, says **Showtime!** and an alert, happy grin is on his face. Concealing and adroit and I don't have an exact word to describe it.

Answer (score 2):

### Sphinx-like

[Definition 1](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/sphinx-like?topic=not-showing-or-feeling-emotions): mysterious and not allowing people to know what you are thinking:

[<sub>2.</sub>](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sphinxlike) enigmatic or inscrutable

> *He sat silently with a sphinx-like smile on his face.*

### Inscrutable

[Definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inscrutable): Difficult to fathom or understand; impenetrable. [from Late Latin *inscrūtābilis*, *scrūtārī* to examine]

Comment: I like these words very much, but I can't say I see how they indicate that process of rapid-and-skillful-concealment that goes on with a person.  Poker-faced is the best I've heard, perhaps

Comment: @NewAlexandria  Perhaps not rapid nor immediate hiding of one's emotions but definitely there is a certain ability implied in both terms. For example, my face has been said to be like an open book; if I feel joy, sadness or irritation it is stamped on my face without any conscious effort on my behalf. No one has ever said it is difficult to know what I am thinking! To pretend to experience different feelings is a "skill" (not sure I would class it as such) that I'd imagine one could become adept through practice or by sheer necessity.

Answer (score 1):

Belie - to give a false idea or impression of something

> His bright smile **belied** his actual mood, which was really one of great sadness.

Veneer - a way of behaving or appearing that gives other people a false idea of your true feelings or situation

> A rigid **veneer** of courtesy hid her mounting fury.

Dissemble - to hide your true feelings, opinions, etc.

> He **dissembled** happiness at the news that his old girlfriend was getting married—to someone else

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE! While these are useful, please read the [Stack Exchange policy](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and [our Meta post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4981/18696) on referencing the work of others. Please use the `>` symbol to indicate quotes from elsewhere, and offer a minimal citation and a link.

Comment: Besides 'mask' and 'poker face', "dissimulate" and "dissemble" seem to most-often have the usage that was the focus of my question: *the swift-covering of the natural response*.  I am specifically looking to identify that a natural reaction began, *evanescently*, and was deftly replaced by another visage.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are words to describe swift or skilful, I don't believe there is a specific word to describe skilful at hiding emotions per se.

[Adroit](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adroit?&path=/) might be a reasonable fit in this instance, as in: *he was adroit at disguising his true feelings*, whilst *[adept](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adept?s=t)* might be another.

Answer (score 0):

> eccedentesiast

Someone who hides behind a smile, when all they want to do is hide and/or die. ( There is so many, they actually made a word for it.)
She's eccedentesiast after she had to break up with Dylan...

This was taken from the Urban dictionary.

Comment: There's also a collins dictionary definition.

Answer (score -1):

Are any of the following appropriate?

Artful

Disingenuous

Beguiling

Slick

There is wilful concealment implied in all these words I think.

Comment: You should compile all the suggestions in the comments into your answer, so that it would be (possibly?) voted as the answer.

Comment: @BlessedGeek I disagree, that would be akin to co-opting someone else's answer. User49727 would do well to say "why" his/her suggestions are valid rather than asking the OP's opinion.

Comment: Someone has to do it - to provide closure to the question, where the closure is amply provided in the comments.

Comment: @BlessedGeek The first answer in a comment was yours - you do it!

Comment: Agreed, @TrevorD.  I see people do this ALL THE TIME across stackexchange sites.  I wish there was a large survey of users' choices, in regards like these.  Many times, I stop writing a comment and instead write an answer.  Are people trying to be too-perfect?